# Setting access rights when using shared folders with vmware fusion

Tags: linux, macos, vmware-fusion, shared-folders

I have CentOS 6.5 minimal guest, and OSX Mavericks 10.9 host. The player is VMWare Fusion. I want to edit files on host and run them on guest. I am trying to use shared folders to achieve this.

A folder from host can be seen on guest as `/mnt/hgfs/www`. I create a symlink to `/vol/sites/www` where the project is configured and code should be executed.

It order to run, source files should have `apache:apache` owner. But I can see they have `games` owner. I understand that there are completely different users on Mac and Centos, but even running `chmod -R 777` on the host does not help.

Can I change `games` user to make things work? Any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this solution?  http://viraj-workstuff.blogspot.com/2013/07/vmware-fusion-permissions-on-shared.html

If you try this, I would back up the VMWare services file first, so you can replace it if something goes wrong:  `sudo cp /etc/vmware-tools/services.sh VM_services_backup.sh`.  If it works, you can delete the backup afterward.

Apparently the downside is this has to be repeated when VMWare makes changes or updates to VMWare Tools.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't find ` /etc/vmware-tools/services.sh` file on my guest

Comment: Can rsync be a more stable solution?

Comment: You can see the shared folder, so presumably VMWare Tools is running, but you can always check: `status vmware-tools`.  Does `/etc/vmware-tools/services.sh restart` work to restart the service?  I thought that would be pretty general for Linux VM's.  Unfortunately, the VM I work with is Windows so I can't really check these things quickly.

Comment: It was a real pain installing vmware tools on centOS. `status vmware-tools` returns `Unknown job: vmware-tools`.